# Debugging not working with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7

I tried to running a website in debug more (F5), and I get the following error message. Note, that I am using a local IIS 7 server on windows 7 64 bit machine.

How can I get the debugger to work?

[image]

Comment: Did you create a virtual directory corresponding to the application URL

Comment: I added a website using IIS 7 manager. I'm not sure why or how to add a virtual directory

Comment: Can you goto `http://localhost/[subdirectoryhere]`  ?

Comment: ya, I can browse the website.

Comment: Could you go into visual studio, right click on the project you are trying to debug (the web project) go into properties. From there, go into Web and scroll to the bottom. Take a screen shot and share that? My thought is that perhaps you have VS aimed at the wrong IIS location. Please post a comment on here once you do so I see that the post was updated.

Comment: I got it working by setting IIS authentication to use 'windows authentication' and by running vs as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above:

I got it working by setting IIS authentication to use 'windows authentication' and by running visual studio as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to accomplish local debugging with IIS 7, I may have another solution for you. I developed a small port opener I called "SharpProxy" that may make your local testing much easier.

Overview and instructions: http://www.codefromjames.com/wordpress/?p=97

It's open source! Get code here: https://github.com/jocull/SharpProxy